# Replacing /bin/bash with /bin/false in /etc/passwd file

Tags: bash, script, solaris

I am writing a program to disable users from a system, i want to replace `/bin/bash` to `/bin/false.`

Example

```
xxx:x:1:22:xx:/export/home/xx:**/bin/bash**
```

replace to

```
xxx:x:1:22:xx:/export/home/xx:**/bin/false**
```

I want do with using bash script.

I know one way to do this is using `sed`. But i am not good at regular expressions.

Can any one help?

Comment: mv /bin/bash /tmp/bin/false

Comment: @Stepo That just makes `/bin/bash` unavailable to everyone.

Comment: ah gosh, I see. you're right!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well you don't do it at all with `sed` or regular expressions. What you do is to use the program [chsh](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chsh) to change the shell of a user.

```
chsh -s /bin/false username
```

alternatively:

```
usermod -s /bin/false username
```

If you wanted to replace it with an actual shell you'd also have to make sure that it is listed in `/etc/shells`.

Comment: chsh says command not found!! i am using solaris

Comment: @user1212207: on my `SunOS 5.8 SUNW,UltraAX-i2` ther *is* a `usermod`. And it even supports `-s`. I stand by my answer.

Comment: yeah usermod works fine!!! and solved my problem

Answer (score 5):

Please be aware that `chsh` is not always available! in **alpine** Linux for example or embeded systems using **busybox** ..

Simple inline `sed` command :

`sed -i '/www-data/s/false/sh/g' /etc/passwd`

(This example changes shell from */bin/false* to */bin/sh* for user *www-data* )